# Effective Sample Size for Weighted Samples

Tags: inference, sample-size, markov-chain-montecarlo, sample, weights

I have an MCMC sampler with weighted samples and I want to compute effective sample size at every step to determine sample degeneracy. I am using the following formula:

$ESS = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^N{w_i})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i^2}$

I realized that this metric does not measure effective sample size well when MCMC algorithm works badly.

For instance, suppose that all samples degenerate into one bad sample, i.e. $x_1 = x_2 = ... = x_N$. Then, after assigning weights (by likelihood $p(y|x_i)$) all samples will have the same weight thus $ESS$ is equal to $N$ while in fact there is only one sample representing the distribution.

Are there alternative ways to compute $ESS$ for MCMC?

Comment: Your ESS definition seems to be the one from Importance Sampling, and not from MCMC. What are the $w$s?

Comment: @Greenparker $w_i$s are the weights that are assigned to propagated particles after receiving observation at time $t$, i.e. $p(y_t|x_t)$.